# How do devices add DNS entries on a local network?

Tags: dns

I have a D-Link WiFi extender DAP-1320, and somehow, when it gets plugged in, it enables my Linux box to resolve `dlinkap.local` to its IP address.  I don't have to add anything to `/etc/hosts`.

In the old days, everything worked out of `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/resolv.conf`, but poking around `/etc/resolv.conf` now, I see "resolver" manages that file, and any changes I make will get overwritten.

I miss the old days of Linux a little bit :)

Anyway, what is the mechanism for a device allowing a network it gets plugged into to recognize it by name?  Is a bonjour thing, or UPnP?  How does it work?

Comment: What Linux distribution is it? Is “resolver” really what manages the file, or is it “resolvconf”?

Answer (score 1):

DHCP clients usually send their name to the DHCP server.  The name is usually recorded in the lease file, and may be added to the local DNS server as an entry under the default domain.  (Some routers will use `.local`, although `.localnet` would be more appropriate.)  If you have a registered domain consider setting the domain on the router to sub-domain such as `lan.example.com`.

The `.local` domain is usually used for auto-discovery.  Their are several names used for this service such as `mdns`, `bonjour`, and `avahi`.   Modern resolvers will often return names from this service.

Depending on the operating system, you can check for DNS entries using the `nslookup` or `host` command.  This will only return a value if the name is returned from DNS.  The resolver library uses multiple sources including DNS, `/etc/hosts`, and optionally others including mDNS, NIS, LDAP, and more.  On Linux these should be listed in the `etc/nsswitch.conf` file.

You can check for the `avahi-daemon` processes with the command `ps -ef | grep [a]vahi`.  The command `avahi-resolve --name` can be used to lookup fully qualified names using the auto-discovery services.

Comment: But with my modem/router being my DHCP server, don't I have to point something on my linux box at it for it to be queried as a DNS server?

Comment: @GregBell It depends on the distribution.  Some distributions use automatic configuration of the resolver configuration.  This will include the hooks in the DHCP client to write the DNS server data to a known location and invoke the resolver configuration utility.  Otherwise, you need to edit /etc/resolve.conf yourself. When resolv.conf is automatically gernerated, it usually has an warning about editing.

Comment: Yep, Ubuntu uses 'resolver' - no editing of /etc/resolve.conf.  But I'm wondering if I have to point NetworkManager or something else at my router to say "go use this device to resolve".

Comment: @GregBell The resolvconf package handles setting up resolv.conf when DHCP connects.  It drops a file in /etc/dhcp/dclient-enter-hooks.d.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily check whether it's Multicast DNS (bonjour) by browsing the list of known hosts.

```
$ avahi-browse -a
```